# What should be the "input_tensor_name" during model conversion from frozen graph to tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I trained a semantic segmentation model with my own dataset using the python scripts available on Deeplab's official [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) page.
Both the training and testing went well.

Then I exported my model to a frozen graph using [export_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/export_model.py) with this command:

```
python3 export_model.py \
   --model_variant="xception_65" \
   --crop_size=354 \
   --crop_size=354 \
   --atrous_rates=6 \
   --atrous_rates=12 \
   --atrous_rates=18 \
   --output_stride=16 \
   --checkpoint_path=model.ckpt-1000 \
   --export_path=frozen_inference_graph_354X354.pb
```

This also succeed. Now I want to convert my frozen graph to tflite using [convert_to_tflite.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/convert_to_tflite.py) . This script has 2 input parameters that I don't understand: "**input_tensor_name**" and "**output_tensor_name**" . Should I leave the value the default "**ArgMax:0**" value for "**output_tensor_name**". What should be the value of "**input_tensor_name**" ?

```
python3 convert_to_tflite.py \
   --quantized_graph_def_path=frozen_inference_graph_354X354.pb \
   --output_tflite_path=model.tflite \
   --input_tensor_name="?" \
   --output_tensor_name="?"
```

I couldn't find any documentation regarding to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try with custom names and get back if conversion failed.

Comment: If succeed ,analyse with netron the generated file

Comment: What do you mean by custom names? I can't write just random things

Comment: What version of Tensorflow have u used?

Comment: I'm using version 1.15.0

Comment: Please use [this link](https://tfhub.dev/s?publisher=sayakpaul&q=deeplab) to find extensive work on that conversion process by Sayak Paul. Each of these models comes with Colab Notebooks that demonstrate the model conversion and Python inference process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at the documentation, specifically, the [quantize](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/quantize.md) markdown document.

In that document you can find a valid `--input_tensor_name=MobilenetV2/MobilenetV2/input:0`

You need to train a quantization aware model using one of the strategies shown in the document by tinkering with the parameter `--quantize_delay_step`

In order to do the training, it's likely you'll need at least tensorflow==1.15.3. See [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20867)

If you do all the above, your frozen graph will have a valid input tensor with the specified name. You can check that by searching for the specific node name using [Netron](https://netron.app/). Finally, create the tflite model using `convert_to_tflite.py` script

Comment: Yes, I figured that out by now, that I cannot convert to tflite a model trained on "xception_65" architecture, I have to use the MobilenetV2 architecture instead, and use the tensor that you also specified. Anyway, I will accept your answer since it may help others.